# How do I get simple_form and bootstrap to work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using `simple_form` to generate my forms in my Rails application. I'm wanting to use bootstrap with these forms. So I've installed the following gems and added them to my gemfile... (1)`simple_form`, (2)`twitter-bootstrap-rails`. Finally, per instructions on the simple_form git page I ran, `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`.

After running `bundle install` everything is installed and the server runs.  The forms however are still not displaying correctly as they would with the class "form-control".

**Form**

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: { multipart: :true, class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  = f.input :headshot_image, as: :file
  = f.input :remote_headshot_image_url, placeholder: "Image Url"
  = f.input :first_name, required: true
  = f.input :middle_name
  = f.input :last_name, required: true
```

I am able to get it to "work" by two different methods (neither of which I believe are correct).  First I can add `, class: "form-control"` to each input, or I can add to the simple_form_for `:defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "form-control" } }`. The former which kinda defeats the purpose I believe, and the latter works, but it also applies the class to the file input which is not ideal.

Is there a setup step that I missed? Or have I done something incorrect.  If I need to provide more information or left something out please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: have you restarted the server ? Every time you install a gem..make sure that you restart the server

Comment: @RahulSambari, yes i did. Still nothing.

Comment: are you getting any error or just simple_form with bootstrap is not reflecting >?

Comment: Simple form shows fine and works properly just no bootstrap unless I attach the classes to the controls myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot about adding bootstrap assets to application.css file
simple_form Readme has following line:

> You have to be sure that you added a copy of the Bootstrap assets on your application.

Comment: Do I need to download a copy and put it in the assets folder if I already have installed the 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem?

Comment: No, but you probably didn't include them in application.js

Comment: I have this in application js `//= require twitter/bootstrap` and `*= require bootstrap_and_overrides` in my application.css

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I thought that your forms have correct classes.

just checkout this link https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb and whole example projects. 
Compare its initializers with yours

Comment: so finally figured it out thanks to you pointing out the website in your comments.  Right now if you put `gem simple_form` in your gemfile it will get you version 3.0.2, when you actually need 3.1.0.rc2 at least i believe.  So after putting in `gem 'simple_form', '~>3.1.0.rc2'` in my gemfile and doing a bundle update AND copying/pasting the file here(https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb) to my own project it resolved the issue for me. Thanks again!